# How to center an image with cover in css without using javascript

Tags: css

```js
function set_bg_container_height() {
  let e = document.getElementById("bg_container");
  e.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}

window.onresize = function() {
  set_bg_container_height();
}

set_bg_container_height();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#bg_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* will be overruled by javascript */
}

#bg_image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg_container">
  <img id="bg_image" src="eyes1.jpg">
</div>
```

I want an image in the background just large enough that it always covers the window.
Without javascript I get:

[image]

Or other unwanted behaviour. Is it possible without using javascript?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: CSS doesn't suck that hard though

Answer (score 0):

You can also put `background-position` property in your css file which has value of `x-axis` and `y-axis` along with `center` you can do it like that `background-position:center;` or like `background-position:x-axis y-axis` or `background-position:aSingleValueForBothAxis`,
I sure hope this will solve your problem